# Does a Galera equivalent for Postgres exist?

Tags: postgresql, database, galera

I've been working with Galera for a number of months and like the failover along with the redundancy. I've got a Postgres DB that is in testing and will probably move to production. Is there a Galera equivalent for Postgres?  I read about "standby" DBs for Postrgres but not sure they are the same thing as Galera with regards to automatic failover/VIP.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling

Comment: postgres-XL probably be the closest to Galera.

Answer (score 3):

While looking for the same, I stumbled upon the very interesting [stolon](https://github.com/sorintlab/stolon) project, which announces itself as 
"PostgreSQL cloud native High Availability and more" and includes walkthroughs for setting up clusters and on Kubernetes.